# How to force HTTPS to subdomain (no www)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

**How can I force any user to the following url while forcing HTTPS?**

`https://subdomain.hostname.com/request-uri`

**From all of these links:**

`http://hostname.com/request-uri`

`http://www.hostname.com/request-uri`

`https://hostname.com/request-uri`

`https://www.hostname.com/request-uri`

**I tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* https://subdomain.hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**And:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostname\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Without having any success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?hostname\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} '=hostname.com' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} '=www.hostname.com'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.hostname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this will redirect **all** of the request to *hostname.com* or to *www.hostname.com* to the subdomain.

If you need to redirect only specific *request-uri*, than you need something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} '=hostname.com' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} '=www.hostname.com'
RewriteRule ^(.*request-uri)$ https://subdomain.hostname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only needed the first one though. I used @starkeen his answer and haven't tested this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hostname.com
    Redirect / https://subdomain.hostname.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.hostname.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

Check this: [Simple Redirection](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect)